# rxjava android testing for a typical REST query

Tags: android, integration-testing, rx-java

I'm trying to perform an integration test between a REST server and my Android application.
In short, my app does a get query to obtain an array of json elements ('scenarios').
My test passes, but is all but elegant and efficient, as I introduced a 10 sec latency.
I'd prefer something like 'observationThread.join()' just before my final assertion, but I did not find the way so far.
Any idea?

Here is my code:

```
public void test_should_return_2_scenarios() throws InterruptedException {
    ScenarioBoundary scenarioBoundary = new ScenarioBoundary();
    final List<Scenario> scenarios = new LinkedList<Scenario>();
    ImmediateScheduler immediateScheduler = (ImmediateScheduler) Schedulers.immediate();
    scenarioBoundary.getObservableScenarios().subscribeOn(immediateScheduler).observeOn(immediateScheduler).subscribe(new Observer<Scenario>() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void onCompleted() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Completed");
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            assertFalse("Error when testing scenario retrieval!", true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Scenario scenario) {
            Log.d(TAG, scenario.toString());
            scenarios.add(scenario);
        }
    });
    immediateScheduler.createWorker().schedule(new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            assertEquals(2, scenarios.size());
        }
    }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toBlocking()` method to block the Observable and get the final result. E.g.,

```
public void test_should_return_2_scenarios() throws InterruptedException {
    ScenarioBoundary scenarioBoundary = new ScenarioBoundary();
    List<Scenario> scenarios = scenarioBoundary.getObservableScenarios().toList().toBlocking().single();
    List<Scenario> expectedScenarios = ...;
    assertEquals(expectedScenarios, scenarios);
}
```

More info: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Blocking-Observable-Operators